# Debugging With RavenDB Is Horrendously Slow

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDB version 2.0.3.0. When the debugger is attached, everything involving RavenDB runs horrendously slow. Every query takes several seconds to complete.

If I press pause while the debugger is just sitting there, I always see it hung up with the following call trace:

> Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.FastCharStream.Refill() Line 91  C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.FastCharStream.ReadChar() Line 53    C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserTokenManager.JjMoveNfa_3(int startState, int curPos) Line 604 + 0x1b bytes    C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserTokenManager.JjMoveStringLiteralDfa0_3() Line 94 + 0xd bytes  C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParserTokenManager.GetNextToken() Line 1379 + 0x9 bytes C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Jj_ntk() Line 1929 + 0x1d bytes  C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Clause(string field) Line 1373 + 0x1d bytes  C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Query(string field) Line 1301 + 0xc bytes    C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(string field) Line 1287 + 0xc bytes    C#
>       Lucene.Net.dll!Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser.Parse(string query) Line 223 + 0xf bytes C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Indexing.QueryBuilder.BuildQuery(string query, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery indexQuery, Raven.Database.Indexing.RavenPerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzer) Line 56 + 0xe bytes  C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.GetLuceneQuery(string query, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery indexQuery) Line 1120 + 0x1d bytes C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.GetLuceneQuery() Line 1081 + 0x28 bytes    C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Indexing.Index.IndexQueryOperation.Query() Line 803 + 0x26 bytes  C#
>       [External Code] 
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Query.AnonymousMethod__8e(Raven.Database.Storage.IStorageActionsAccessor actions) Line 1220 + 0x145 bytes    C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase.Query(string index, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery query) Line 1237  C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryRunner.ExecuteActualQuery(Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery query, Raven.Database.Data.DynamicQueryMapping map, System.Tuple touchTemporaryIndexResult, string realQuery) Line 82 + 0x32b bytes C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryRunner.ExecuteDynamicQuery(string entityName, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery query) Line 49 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       Raven.Database.dll!Raven.Database.Queries.DynamicQueryExtensions.ExecuteDynamicQuery(Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase self, string entityName, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery indexQuery) Line 19 + 0x11 bytes   C#
>       Raven.Client.Embedded.dll!Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseCommands.Query(string index, Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery query, string[] includes, bool metadataOnly, bool indexEntriesOnly) Line 389 + 0x47 bytes   C#
>       Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll!Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery>.ExecuteActualQuery() Line 535 + 0x50 bytes C#
>       Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll!Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery>.InitSync() Line 518    C#
>       Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll!Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery>.QueryResult.get() Line 505 C#
>       Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll!Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor.ExecuteQuery() Line 1425 + 0x1b bytes    C#
>       Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll!Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor.Execute(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expression) Line 1398 + 0x3d bytes  C#

If I run without the debugger attached, everything performs fine and fast... I've never encountered this problem before yesterday.

I'm using an EmbeddableDocumentStore with DataDir=~\App_Data\RavenDB.

I tried deleting the RavenDB directory, but even with a completely fresh DB, Raven is still just as slow.

Any idea what's wrong or how I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliTrace, shut it down.
In exception settings, mark Just My Code and don't stop on handled exceptions.

Comment: No change. It's literally instant when running without the debugger attached. I have no breakpoints set, no watches, no Intellitrace, and Just My Code turned on...though what's interesting is that when I hit pause I DO see the full Raven/Lucene call stack in the Call Stack window...not just "External Code"...not sure if that's normal

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue for a while until we discovered that we were creating indexes on each requests (due to a wrong IoC registration of the DocumentStore).

We ensured that this line is called once per application init and the slowness vanished:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(MyIndex).Assembly, store);
```